# Routing in ASP.NET Core without a 'slash'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-routing

All routing examples are using the `/` character, for example:

`/{category}/{product}/{id}`
for
`/computer/mainboard/13`

Is it possible to use a comma `,`, instead of `/`? For example:

`/{category},{product},{id}` for `/computer,mainboard,13`

Comment: ```/computer,mainboard,13```


```/computer/mainboard/13```

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, maybe I'm doing something else wrong...
I'm new to .net core

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

I tested on ASP.NET Core 2.2.

TestController.cs:

```cs
[Route("test")]
public class TestController :Controller
{
    [HttpGet("somepath/{a},{b},{c}")]
    public IActionResult Test(string a, string b, int c)
    {
        return Ok($"a: {a}, b: {b}, c: {c}");
    }
}
```

StartUp.cs:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
}
```

When opening `http://localhost:5000/test/somepath/abc,def,123` I get the expected output:

```
a: abc, b: def, c: 123
```

Comment: I think,
routing parameters name MUST BE the same as constructor parameters name... (a,b,c)

[HttpGet("somepath/{a},{b},{c}")]

public IActionResult Test(string a, string b, int c)

Comment: What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: in your example code, could you write that:  public IActionResult Test(string x, string y, int z)

Comment: No, the parameter names have to match. :)